# How to limit download speed using UnityWebRequest?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Most files of our game is download during playing. If the download speed has no limit, there is not network traffic space left for the game play protocols... I tried to use the "DownloadHandlerScript", and provide a array of "preallocatedBuffer" to control the accept content size from web per frame, but it look like unuseful...Can anyone help me please?

Here is the DownloadHandlerScript I use:

```
class CustomDownloadHandler : DownloadHandlerScript
{
    private byte[] _cacheBytes;
    private int _index;

    public CustomDownloadHandler(byte[] preallocatedBuffer) : base(preallocatedBuffer)
    {

    }

    protected override void ReceiveContentLength(int contentLength)
    {
        _cacheBytes = new byte[contentLength];
    }

    // this method will be called once per frame to hand chunks of that data to script.
    protected override bool ReceiveData(byte[] buffer, int dataLength)
    {
        if (buffer == null || buffer.Length <= 0)
            return false;

        Array.Copy(buffer, 0, _cacheBytes, _index, dataLength);
        _index += dataLength;

        return true;
    }

    //...
}
```

And I create an UnityWebRequest like this:

```
bytes = new byte[4096]; //As preallocated buffer.

webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get("url/file.assetbundle");
webRequest.downloadHandler = new CustomDownloadHandler(bytes);
webRequest.SendWebRequest();
```

But the download speed is same whether I use the downloadhandler or not...

Comment: can you show me some code it will help me to understand what exactly you are going to achieve

Comment: I just add my code, please have a look at it ...@zain ul din

Comment: I don't see what makes you think the custom download handler you have there would have any influence on the bandwidth usage during a download ...

Comment: And I don't think this is currently possible .. there were requests for this e.g. [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/is-there-any-way-to-control-the-download-and-upload-speed-of-unitywebrequest.527461/) and [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/limit-download-speed.514121/) but I don't think something like this was ever implemented

Comment: Because the "ReceiveData" method is call once per frame as far as I know... @derHugo

Comment: @link yes .. so? we have no clue how the WebRequest works internally so it is as well possible that the data has already been received and is now only copied into the buffer before every frame ... You can try of course and really reduce that buffer to something very small like `new byte[16]` and see if this makes a difference in the network bandwidth .. otherwise it might just slow down the copy process but not really the download itself

Comment: "reduce that buffer to something very small" yeah I arleady tried that.. Still it doesn't work... I think you are right

Comment: According to Unity's Docs, "The size of the byte array limits the amount of data delivered to the ReceiveData callback each frame. If your data arrives slowly, over many frames, you may have provided too small of a byte array". But actually it does not work at all... It is so confusing@derHugo

Comment: The only way to do this is to roll your own _download everything_ handlers.  Only then can you have fine-grain control.